# Can I use "include" on a server to share libraries between applications?

Tags: php

I have a number of web sites which use sub domains and are all in their own directory on the web server. 99% of the files in each are the same, with a handful of files which are different and peculiar to each sub domain.

I'm familiar with the include statement, but is there a way for me to have all the "core" php files in one directory, and only the unique ones in the sub domain directory and they can then reference the core ones? This would save having to maintain several copies of the same file... not good practice!

Something like this...

```
+-core_file_directory -index.php
|                     -file1.php
|                     -file2.php
|
+-sub_domain_1 - subdom_scheme.css
|              - unique_file.php
|
+-sub_domain_2 - subdom_scheme.css
|              - unique_file.php
|
+-sub_domain_3 - subdom_scheme.css
               - unique_file.php
```

I need an index.php in each sub directory, but assume I could include the index.php in the core folder? Can I include a relative path? "..\core_file_directory\index.php"?

I'm guessing this would also be more secure, in that core files are not directly public facing...?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes you can just try it!

Comment: Can you explain your question more?

Comment: Thanks Xetolone. I just wanted to check I can do this before wasting hours trying to get it to work! :-)

Comment: what happens if you try what your suggesting?

Comment: Managing several subdomains this way can also be a problem. What if a core file produces an error in one site but not in another? Your common code becomes a single point of failure. You could create a self-hosted composer package (which you can host locally or in a local GitLab for example).

Comment: Thanks Peter, but to me a single point of failure is easier to fix. It also ensures none of the sub directories are left behind with updates to the core files. I'd have to look into the composer package as it's something I've not heard of. Might consider this for future development

Comment: Sure you can find tutorials like these: https://php.watch/articles/composer-gitlab-repositories - also when you write include, I hope you mean `require_once()` : )

Comment: Appreciated Peter.

Comment: Shared PHP libraries on a server used to be a thing over 10 years ago, it is now considered bad practice. Deployment strategies have moved on a lot. One used to have a server where a library (e.g. Symfony) was installed globally, and then all Symfony apps would reference that library. But these days an app should be subject to automated testing based on the libraries it is bundled with - which is not possible if a library is shared. In practice, several apps on a server will use different versions of Symfony, and upgrading a shared copy would be liable to break something.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? "Can I include a relative path" sounds like a question that could be simply answered by trying it. Whether this is a good idea is a debatable question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Note however that relative directories are relative to "the current working directory" when the script runs, which is not always what you expect.

The best way is to specify the paths using [the magic constant `__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) which gives the absolute path of the file where you type it. So rather than `include "..\core_file_directory\index.php";` you would write `include __DIR__ . "\..\core_file_directory\index.php";`

The other thing that will make your life a lot easier is to use [class autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to avoid long lists of includes at the top of each file. That will also make it much easier to move things around later (e.g. to put the shared classes into a reusable package rather than a central directory) because only the autoloader needs to know the directory layout.